# Is it possible to install Geoserver on Zentyal?

Tags: geoserver, linux

We want to setup a small WebGIS environment based on Geoserver/PostGIS or even the OpenGeoSuite if possible.
Our Server runs on Zentyal. Is it possible to install  Geoserver and PostGIS on Zentyal and if so is there any documentation available?
Or what would be an easy to operate platform so that we can create our WebGIS (we do not have much experience in running web servers though).

Answer (score 1):

As long the application you want to install does not change Zentyal created configfiles, it is very well possible to install the application. Depending on the version of Zentyal you use, applications that can be installed on the base OS (Ubuntu 10.04 for Zentyal 2.x and Ubuntu 12.04 for Zentyal 3.x) can also be installed on Zentyal.